# Is it possible to run automation using Appium 1.4 with Xcode 8 +

Tags: xcode, automation, appium, instruments, appium-ios

I have tried using Appium 1.4 with Xcode 8 and its not working as they Appium 1.4 doesn't support Xcode 8 but this works fine with Xcode 7.
Is there any loophole which can be exploited to make use of Appium 1.4 and Xcode 8 or any tools which might help me doing this.
Reason : Can run automation on Appium 1.4 and use Xcode 8 to run the instrument for the same automation suite.(**build is generated from Xcode 8**)

Comment: XCode 8 is not having UIAutomtaion  in Instruments. Just give a try, Solution 1. copy the UIAutomation from Xcode 7 and create same path and paste it in Xcode 8 then try. Solution 2. Keep both Xcode 7(require rename this)and Xcode 8, In Appium -> iOS Advance setting change the Xcode path to Xcode 7. One more thing, for iOS 10 you must use xcode 8. The second solution works fine, I tried out.